# create random vector by group

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. `df1` is a collection of people ids (`x`) by groups (`y`)

```
df1 <- tibble(x = seq(1:40),
              y = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d",
                    "b", "b", "c", "c", "a",
                    "a", "d", "d", "b", "d",
                    "a", "b", "a", "c", "d",
                    "a", "b", "a", "c", "d",
                    "b", "b", "c", "c", "a",
                    "a", "d", "d", "b", "d",
                    "a", "b", "a", "c", "d")
              )
df1
# A tibble: 40 x 2
#       x y    
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 a    
# 2     2 b    
# 3     3 a    
# 4     4 c    
# 5     5 d    
# 6     6 b    
# 7     7 b    
# 8     8 c    
# 9     9 c    
#10    10 a    
# … with 30 more rows
```

`df2` gives the probability of "Yes" (`z`) for each group (`y`).

```
df2 <- tibble(y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
              z = c(.45, .54, .78, .34)
              )
df2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  y         z
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a      0.45
#2 b      0.54
#3 c      0.78
#4 d      0.34
```

I want to create a vector of random "Yes"/"No" for everyone in `df1` using the group "Yes" probabilities. Here's what it might look like just for group "a". I want this for all 40 people in `df1`. Is there a handy dplyr method?

```
df1 %>%
  filter(y=="a") %>%
  mutate(rand = sample(c("Yes", "No"), n(), replace=TRUE, prob = c(.45, 1-.45)))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
#       x y     rand 
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 a     Yes  
# 2     3 a     No   
# 3    10 a     Yes  
# 4    11 a     No   
# 5    16 a     Yes  
# 6    18 a     Yes  
# 7    21 a     No   
# 8    23 a     Yes  
# 9    30 a     Yes  
#10    31 a     No   
#11    36 a     Yes  
#12    38 a     No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the datasets by `'y'` and `sample` the values based on `z` value in `df2`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'y') %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(rand = sample(c("Yes", "No"), n(), replace=TRUE, 
                 prob = c(first(z), 1- first(z))))
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't know about `first()`. Slick.

Comment: I have taken `first` value but you can actually take any value from `z` column since all the values in them would be the same for each `y`.